# sigma algebra generated by fraction of random variables (continued)

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are positive i.i.d. random variables.
Let $S=X_1+X_2+X_3$. Is this true that
$$
\sigma(X_1,X_2)\subset\sigma(X_1/S,X_2/S)?
$$
Any hint of this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega=\{1,2\}^3$ with the uniform probability law, and let $X_i$ be the projection onto the $i$th coordinate. Then $\mathcal{F}_1=\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ contains the event 
$$\{X_1=1\}=\{(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,1),(1,2,2)\}$$

Suppose for contradiction that $\mathcal{F}_2=\sigma(\frac{X_1}{S},\frac{X_2}{S})$ also contains this event. Since $\mathcal{F}_2$ contains the events
$$\Big\{\frac{X_1}{S}=\frac{1}{4}\Big\}=\{(1,1,2),(1,2,1)\}$$
and
$$\Big\{\frac{X_2}{S}=\frac{2}{5}\Big\}=\{(1,2,2),(2,2,1)\}$$
it follows that $\mathcal{F}_2$ contains
$$ \{(1,1,1)\}=\{X_1=1\}\setminus\Big(\Big\{\frac{X_1}{S}=\frac{1}{4}\Big\}\cup\Big\{\frac{X_2}{S}=\frac{2}{5}\Big\}\Big)$$

But this is a contradiction because $\{(1,1,1),(2,2,2)\}$ is an atom in $\mathcal{F}_2$: it's impossible to distinguish between $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,2,2)$ using $\frac{X_1}{S}$ and $\frac{X_2}{S}$. Therefore $\mathcal{F}_1\not\subset\mathcal{F}_2$.